# Emission shader not working

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission

Why in evee does the emission shader not actually emit light? I turn it up to extreme levels and it does not work.

Comment: check blooom and upload pictures

Comment: In EEVEE, you need to bake the effect of the indirect light from the emission by using an "Irradiance Volume"

Comment: you can also add a light to fake the emission